# Angular2: Not able to install xml2json

Tags: angular

I am not able to install xml2json. i referred many other post but nothing worked. it gives error every time i run npm install xml2json

please help and also provide any working example of xml to json

```js
C:\employee>npm install xml2json

> node-expat@2.3.15 install C:\employee\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\employee\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:454:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:480:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:112:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\employee\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v7.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok
employee@0.0.0 C:\employee
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.10

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/tsc-wrapped@4.0.2 requires a peer of typescript@^2.1.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN tsickle@0.21.6 requires a peer of typescript@^2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xml2json"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\employee\npm-debug.log
```

[image: Expat error]

Comment: Still not able to install xml2json

Answer (score 1):

you need install python 2 first.

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: i have installed npm install -g node-gyp but still gives me error

Comment: you need install python 2 first, after python installed, you run command to install node-gyp again

Answer (score 0):

`xml2json` has a dependency on `node-expat` which has a dependency on `node-gyp` which requires you to install [Python 2.7 (not 3.6)](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

**Important:** Check the [installation instructions](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) and follow the steps according to your operating system.

For example, on Windows you need also to run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` **as an admin** so that you will not run into [MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/307).

Also don't forget to check also the [installation instructions for node-expat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expat#windows).

Comment: when i host my application on tomcat ... what all things do i need to take care for above settings ... any reference how to host angular 2 app on tomcat

Comment: notable to install node-expat ... getting error ... added image in main post

Comment: @Jay in the [node-gyp installation link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) that I provided there, when you are on Windows, you need to `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` **as an admin**. Multiple people has struggled with this until they have read the installation instructions :) - [problem link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/307)

Answer (score 0):

After you install Python, you will need to set a system environment variable called `PYTHON` pointing to the Python installation folder. Then you will need to start a fresh bash/powershell/command session and install xml2json.